# What does this indemnification clause mean?

Tags: contract-law

New law student trying to understand what this paragraph is ultimately trying to establish:

> Promptly after receipt by a person entitled to indemnification pursuant to the foregoing Section 9.1 or 9.2 (the "Indemnified Party") of notice of the commencement of any action, the Indemnified Party will, if a claim in respect thereof is to be or has been made against a party who has agreed to provide indemnification under Section 9.1 or 9.2 (an "Indemnifying Party"), promptly notify in writing the Indemnifying Party of the commencement thereof; but the omission to so notify the Indemnifying Party will not relieve it from any liability which it may have to the Indemnified Party except to the extent the Indemnifying Party is prejudiced by the delay or failure to notify it. In case any such action is brought against an Indemnified Party, and it notifies the Indemnifying Party of the commencement thereof, the Indemnifying Party will be entitled to participate in, and, to the extent that it may wish, jointly with any other Indemnifying Party similarly notified, to assume the defense thereof, subject to the provisions herein stated, with counsel reasonably satisfactory to the Indemnified Party, and after notice from the Indemnifying Party to the Indemnified Party of its election to so assume the defense thereof, the Indemnifying Party will not be liable to the Indemnified Party under this Section 9 for any legal or other expenses subsequently incurred by the Indemnified Party in connection with the defense thereof other than reasonable costs of investigation. The Indemnified Party shall have the right to employ separate counsel in any such action and to participate in the defense thereof, but the fees and expenses of such counsel shall not be at the expense of the Indemnifying Party if the Indemnifying Party has assumed the defense of the action with counsel reasonably satisfactory to the Indemnified Party; provided that the fees and expenses of such counsel shall be at the expense of the Indemnifying Party if (i) the employment of such counsel has been specifically authorized in writing by the Indemnifying Party or (ii) the named parties to any such action (including any impleaded parties) include both the Indemnified Party or parties and the Indemnifying Party and, in the judgement of counsel for the Indemnified Party, it is advisable for the Indemnified Party or parties to be represented by separate counsel (in which case the Indemnifying Party shall not have the right to assume the defense of such action on behalf of the Indemnified Party or parties, it being understood, however, that the Indemnifying Party shall not, in connection with any one such action or separate but substantially similar or related actions in the same jurisdiction arising out of the same general allegations or circumstances, be liable for the reasonable fees and expenses of more than one separate firm of attorneys for the Indemnified Party or parties. No settlement of any action against an Indemnified Part shall be made without the consent of the Indemnifying Party and no Indemnifying Party, in the defense of any such claim or action, shall, except with the consent of the Indemnified Party, consent to entry of any judgment or enter into any settlement which does not include as an unconditional term thereof the giving by the claimant or plaintiff to such Indemnified Party of a release from all liability in respect to such claim or litigation. If the Indemnified Party fails to execute a release or other settlement agreement under circumstances where all of the conditions of the preceding sentence have been met, the Indemnifying Party shall have no further obligation to the Indemnified Party pursuant to this Agreement or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly standard indemnification clause very similar to the relationship of an insured and an insurance company.

The party covered by the indemnification agreement has to cover both the damages suffered and the legal fees incurred by the party covered by the agreement.

There is an exception if late notice of the claim is provided and that causes harm to the covering party.

There is an exception if the covered party hires a lawyer without conferring with the covering party or gets out of hand in terms of what a reasonable defense ought to be.

There is an exception if the case is settled without obtaining a full release of the claims asserted against the covered party.